Reduce Unnecessary Database Entries in Craft CMS After Changing Propagation Settings
In one of our Craft CMS projects, we have accumulated around 100 subsites over the years. This has resulted in a large number of unnecessary database entries due to incorrect propagation settings. Our goal now is to reduce these database entries to only the necessary propagations.
Has anyone experienced a similar situation? When we change the propagation settings, the database entries do not seem to decrease. It appears that simply changing the propagation settings does not reduce the existing entries. Do we need to perform some kind of database migration or manual cleanup to achieve this? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Craft-Version: 3.9.5
PHP-Vesion: 8.1.29
Database:  MariaDB 10.11.6

